# Unable to download google-services.json file from Firebase Console

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-console

I have successfully created project on Firebase Console but after adding package name and fingerprint the browser redirected to error page

> Firefox can’t find the file at https://console.firebase.google.com/m/mobilesdk/projects/xxxxxxxxxxxx/clients/android:com.lorem.ipsum/artifacts/2?param=["getArtifactRequest",null,"android:com.lorem.ipsum","2","xxxxxxxxxxxx"]

I am continuously getting this message while trying to download file from project settings

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was caused by the **Firebase Management API** not being enabled at https://console.cloud.google.com/  (right menu - APIs and Services > Dashboard > click on +Enable APIS and Services - then find the API in question and enable it.

Removing and adding your app again would tell you that too.

> An unexpected error has occurred. [Reason: Firebase Management API is
> not enabled. Please enable the API in the Google Cloud Platform
> console at [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/firebase.googleapis.com?project=_]](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/firebase.googleapis.com?project=_)

[image: add-android-app-to-firebase-project]

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue once.

> Sign out + cache/history clear

solved it.
Also try on different web browser

Comment: s Try with Firefox Browser  because there is a bug with Chrome

Comment: @SudhirBelagali yeah but it looks like chrome 53.0.x is solved it.

Answer (score 2):

If You have Added More than One Google Accounts in Chrome Then Firebase Returns Some Error Messages. For Me,  it returns this error :

> )]}'
>   {"code":7,"errorSpace":"generic","placeholders":{"trackingId":"52214415626247XXXXXX"},"status":403,"message":"backend error"}

Try the same in  New Incognito Window mode(Ctrl+Shift+N) in Chrome.
It works For Me..!!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by logging in with a different browser and viola!! I was able to download then. I was using Chrome first, then switched to Safari and it worked.
An extension on Chrome may block responses from Firebase, maybe an adblocker. But in my case i had no adblockers so I have no idea which extension was blocking responses from Firebase.