# Cannot download google-services.json from firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I'm trying to download `google-services.json` from firebase console. The error is *There was an error. The config file cannot be downloaded at this time.* as it can be seen in the below screenshot.

[image]

There are answers on Stackoverflow which didn't work for me ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315789/unable-to-download-google-services-json-file-from-firebase-console) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876676/firebase-error-when-trying-to-download-google-services-json)). Specifically, clearing cache and history, using a newly installed chrome, trying with firefox and edge, using incognito tabs, didn't work.

What else can be done to get rid of this annoying error?

Comment: You may log an issue with the Firebase support https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: *firebaser here* Sorry that you ran into this problem. That looks like an issue with generating the config file. If the problem persists, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks both, I've filled a bug on Firebase support.

Comment: how did you solve it? can you please help

Comment: @Nbn If you log an issue to Google they will help you. Another solution was to create a new firebase project from scratch and then download the json file. After that you can migrate from the old project to the new one. Not the ideal solution, of course.

Answer (score 11):

For me also I had this issue. Before trying anything, I refreshed/reloaded my page, and it works. After refreshing my page, I was able to download google-services.json file.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem for a while with firebase google

what I did was to open the Developer Options for the web and looked at the request response from google

and I found out that the network response is very clear:

"The Google cloud platform for this project is disabled please go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/firebase.googleapis.com/overview?project=<YOUR_PROJECT> and enable"

but for some reason the UI is very un-clear

Very simple solution, go to the link below and enable your project:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/firebase.googleapis.com/overview?project=

Answer (score 1):

While in my case, the issue was caused by my ad blocker. I opened network monitor through developer tools and found out that my ad blocker was canceling post requests sent by Firebase. Disabling it for Firebase solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case waited 24 hours and then it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was using Brave , stopped ad blocker but still it does not work , **Use Chrome if nothing works** ....it worked for me..